# How to check if server is up and running or not in IE browser only using Powershell

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer

Checking if server or Url is to open in IE and get the response status code from the url after open in browser. Means need to check server availability or not only in IE using powershell.

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense. Could you please:
    - Elaborate on your questions and fix grammar mistakes
    - Provide what you have tried so far and what errors you're getting

Comment: Example Url: https://stackoverflow.com. Need to check this URL is up or down in IE browser using powershell i.e, Get the http response status code from the browser after open in IE.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to open IE? just do an Invoke-WebRequest and then look for what ever you need?

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $URL
```

or

```
(Invoke-WebRequest -Url $URL).ParsedHTML
```

I think [this article](https://www.business.com/articles/create-web-scraping-tool-in-powershell/) would be good for some research :)

**UPDATE**
According to your flowchart, this should be more suited to what you want:

1. Open in IE:

   $ie = New-Object -ComObject internetexplorer.application
   $ie.navigate2("stackoverflow.com")
   $ie.visible = $true
2. Use Invoke-WebRequest to get the status code from the server. It's really as simple as:

   Invoke-WebRequest -Uri stackoverflow.com | Select-Object -ExpandProperty StatusCode

Comment: Required Url has no browser compatibility. check Url aromatically only open the IE and need to get the status code.

Comment: I'm still not 100% sure what you mean. Could you provide a "flowchart" of what you want to happen?

Comment: FLow Chart: (In powershell)
1.Url must be open in IE browser.
2.If server(url hit the server) is up and running good means need to get the response status code is 200.
3.If server is down means need to get the response status code is 40$ or 401, 505 etc.,